Weird behaviour on Bash function
I was trying to copy a local dir with exceptions into another location within a Bash script and kept getting a syntax error message.  I ended up with a minimal example that replicates my problem... which only happens from within a function.
So this works as expected:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

rm -rf /tmp/adir/ && mkdir --parents /tmp/adir/
shopt -s extglob dotglob
cp -ar /some/dir/subdirectory/!(tests|.git) /tmp/adir/
shopt -u extglob dotglob

...but this does not work:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

a_function() {
  rm -rf /tmp/adir && mkdir --parents /tmp/adir
  shopt -s extglob dotglob
  cp -ar /some/dir/subdirectory/!(tests|.git) /tmp/adir
  shopt -u extglob dotglob
}

a_function

The later throws a syntax error:
./test.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.sh: line 6: `    cp -ar /some/dir/subdirectory/!(tests|.git) /tmp/adir/'

Bash version: GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Hope someone can help.

The extglob must be set not only at the line where it's used, but also at the place where the function is declared.
See https://stackoverflow.com/q/65533232/1030675 for the same question and detailed answer.

Yes, that's the trick: just moving shopt -s extglob dotglob out of the function and before its declaration (both are needed) did work.
Thanks a lot.
